# Is there a way to documentally confirm that the whole C++ standard or g++ compiler with hardware satisfy exactly IEEE 754 2008?

Tags: ieee-754

Is there some one place in C++ standard or g++ where it is declerated that the compiler or standard satisfies IEEE-754 2008

I notice some references to IEEE-754 2008 standard in C++17 standard and a lot of them in C++20 standard.
But does it mean that C++ standards satisfy IEEE-754 2008 only in some specific considerations declared in C++ standard(one or another).

Or maybe there is some way to confirm that the whole standard satisfy IEEE-754 2008

How can I confirm documentally, that  the program I wrote will work with fp-numbers in the way IEEE-754 2008 states?
And can I do so?

Comment: How could IEEE-754 (2019) be referenced by ISO C++17, given that the former was still two years in the future when the latter was adopted? ISO C++17 published in December 2017, IEEE-754 (2019) published in July 2019.

Comment: The C++ standard would not declare that it conforms IEEE 754-2008. IEEE 754 is a standard for floating-point implementations, and the C++ standard is not a floating-point implementation. The C++ standard cannot declare that a compiler conforms to IEEE 754 because standard does not control or certify individual compilers. The behaviors specified by the C++ standard are insufficient to guarantee conformance to IEEE 754 (the C++ standard is not a subset of IEEE 754).

Comment: The C standard provides a way for C implementations to declare they conform to IEC 60559, effectively equivalent to IEEE 754, by defining the preprocessor macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`. However, there are C implementations that define this preprocessor macro but do not properly conform to IEEE 754, so it cannot be relied on, and I do not know to what extent C++ inherits this declaration from C.

Comment: Re “How can I confirm documentally, that the program I wrote will work with fp-numbers in the way IEEE-754 2008 states?”: You would need to read the specific documentation of the C++ implementation, including the compiler documentation, the standard library documentation, and possibly documentation for the target hardware and operating system.